# Self-signed https gitlab

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, gitlab

I want to have https over my connection to gitlab.

I executed

```
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/gitlab/ssl/172.29.128.166.key -out /etc/gitlab/ssl/172.29.128.166.crt
```

My gitlab.rb is as follow

```
external_url "https://172.29.128.166:8929/"
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/172.29.128.166.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/172.29.128.166.key"
```

2 Problems:

1) When I go to http://172.29.128.166:8929/, I get

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx
```

I have specified `nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true` so shouldn't it should go to https?

2) When I go to https://172.29.128.166:8929/, I can view the GitLab. However, my chrome says that it is "Not Secured".
I can see a certificate invalid as well.

How can i solve this problem? I am new to this thank you

Answer (score 0):

#1

Have you tried it withOUT the "nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 80".  You already have that covered in the "nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true".

When one specifies "https..." in external_url, nginx stops listening on port 80. "nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true" tells it start listening again on port 80.  Your use of redirect_http_to_https_port is redundant/unnecessary.

#2

> However, my chrome says that it is "Not Secured".

Yep.  The browser is operating as designed.  A self-signed certificate is inherently untrusted because anyone can generate a self-signed certificate.  So you're going to get the warning every time.